# HTML/CSS - Grid Layout Not Responsive

Tags: html, css

When I resize the `textarea` element the other elements are not responsive. A sudden gap appears between the selected `textarea` and the textarea next to it.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.grid-container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: pink;
  display: grid;
  padding: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 40px;
  resize: horizontal;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">

<div class="grid-container">
  <textarea class="item" id="item1">1</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item2">2</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item3">3</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item4">4</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item5">5</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item6">6</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item7">7</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item8">8</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item9">9</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item10">10</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item10">11</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item10">12</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you expect to happen when one textarea is wider than the one below it? Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gap appears because of textareas in the same column and different row. You better use **flex** instead of grid.
In the snippet bellow, I created the two lines by separating items into two different divs. A more responsive way would be to use just one div, combined with [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) and [flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) on children.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.flex-container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-container:not(:last-child) {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.flex-container:not(:first-child) {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.item {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 40px;
  resize: horizontal;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">

<div class="flex-container">
  <textarea class="item" id="item1">1</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item2">2</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item3">3</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item4">4</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item5">5</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item6">6</textarea>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <textarea class="item" id="item7">7</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item8">8</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item9">9</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item10">10</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item10">11</textarea>
  <textarea class="item" id="item10">12</textarea>
</div>
```